# How to select thousands of file in chef recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a lot of csv files that should be placed in a server.

So I put it in a directory `my-cookbook/files/default/` and I want to load all csv files by using `Dir.glob` method, but I don't know how to set proper relative path for it.

```
Dir.glob("#{relative_path}/*.csv").each do |file|
  cookbook_file "/var/foo/#{File.basename(file)}" do
    source File.basename(file)
  end
end
```

I tried with `Dir.glob("*.csv")`, but it didn't work.

How can I load all files in `files/default` directory?

Answer (score -1):

This isn't really how Chef is designed to be used. You would be better off putting all your files in something like a git repo or remote tarball and using things like the `git` or `remote_file` resources to download them. `cookbook_file` is really only a hack for small, one-off things. Honestly I don't really use it much, I would recommend you do the same.

Comment: I see, then I'll put the files to another place. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't actually an answer.